# Create SR with OSLC API - Child Objects Specifications not working

Tags: rest, api, maximo

I have a sample pay load below. I am trying to do two things

1. Create SR
2. Update an existing Specification tagged to Classification.

```
{
    "description": "Request for SR",
    "classstructureid": "1141",
    "siteid": "TEST",
    "ticketspec": [
        {
            "assetattrid": "ASSETNUM",
            "alnvalue": "SN1234",
            "classstructureid": "1141",
            "class": "SR",
        } 

    ]
}
```

This is giving me a 400 BAD REQUEST for the below reason:

When I set the CLassification - the specification is added by default in Ticketspec and hence the create request is not updating the spec - the request is getting rejected.

At the child level i tried

```
_action ="Change"
_action="AddChange"
```

But it's not working.

Any tips please ?

Comment: Can you setup your INTEGRATION logger to level DEBUG, SQL to INFO, try again and post the resulting logs?

Comment: Can you please share the actual error message you are being given?

Comment: 400 Bad Request

Comment: Usually there is a body and error in the body to go with that response from Maximo. If there really isn't one, then your REST call is likely incorrect from the beginning, no matter what action you are trying to take, data you are working on or object structure service you are calling.

Comment: "reasonCode": "BMXAA4211E",
        "message": "BMXAA4211E - Database error number 1 has occurred when operating on TICKETSPEC :  Attribute=ASSETNUM Ticket=29116 Class=SR Section=. Report the error to the owner of the deployment.",
        "statusCode": "400"